# Are bounties infinite?

Tags: diablo-iii

Diablo 3: Reaper of Souls introduced Adventure Mode where the player can collect blood shards and rift tokens to keep playing after the campaign is complete. I'm wondering if bounties are infinitely given? If I finish all the bounties throughout the various acts, will more reappear?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Once you finish all the bounties in a single game, the only thing left to do really is Nephalem rifts. My wife spent the better part of last night doing all twenty-five bounties in one instance, and nothing new spawned.

However, if you just leave the game and start a new one, all the bounties will be refreshed, and you can continue doing bounties indefinitely that way.

Comment: Excellent. Honestly, the Rifts and Bounties are the most fun I've had with Diablo since it came out.